# How can I add input values to a result list below and allow the same text input field to continue to add more?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, list

I have a single text field and an accompanying "add" button:

```
<fieldset id="itemList">
    <input type="text" id="addItem" name="addItem">
    <input type="button" name="add" value="add">
</fieldset>
```

Whenever someone clicks "add" I'd like to add the new item to the list below and clear the input field above.

```
<hr>
<ol id="resultList">
    <li>just example</li>
    <li>new text input</li>
    <li>last entered item</li>
</ol>
```

I'm not sure how to accomplish this in jQuery.  Can you help?

For bonus, I'd like to limit the list to 10.  So I need to somehow count the number of list items and make the above form's display contingent on <11 list items.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('input[name="add"]').click(function() {
        if($('#resultList li').length < 10)
        {    value = $('input[name="addItem"]').val();
             $('ol li:last').after("<li>" + value + "</li>");
             $('input[name="addItem"]').val(""); }
        if($('#resultList li').length == 10)
        {   $('input[name="addItem"]').css("display", "none");
            $('input[name="add"]').css("display", "none"); }
    });
});
```

Working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bhZdz/2/

Edited because I didn't see the last part of your question, form hides after 10th element is added now.

Answer (score 1):

```
function addItem(){
  var list = $("#resultList");
  var count = list.find("li").size();
  if(count < 10){
     var input = $("input[name=addItem]");
     var item = input.val();
     list.append(("<li>"+item+"</li>"));
     input.val(" "); // clear field
  }else{
    // already have 10 items
  }
}
$("input[name=add]").click(addItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 ​$('input[type=button]').click(function(){
    $('#resultList').append('<li>'+$('#addItem').val()+'</li>');
    $('#addItem').val("");
  }
 );​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

You can also use `input[name=add]`